# If image is not wide enough, how to make it stretch to the width of the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, next.js

The image is fine if it's [not full screen](https://ibb.co/f0XDq0n), but [with full screen](https://ibb.co/3zsn3QB), there's a white area on the right (probably because the image is not large enough). How do I make the image automatically stretch so that its width covers the full screen?

CSS (see .landingImage):

```
.body {
  margin: 0px, 50px;
}

.home {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.landingImage {
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

index.js(built using nextjs):

```
<Head>
   ...
 </Head>
 <div id="wrapper">
    <Image className={indexStyles.landingImage} src={orcas} />
  </div>
      <div className={indexStyles.home}>
        <Head>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
          ></meta>

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
          ></link>
        </Head>
        <body>
            ...
        </body>
      </div>
```

tried width: 100% also didn't work

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the layout in Next.JS, but it appears as if you are loading your image component inside of your HTML heading tags? Is that correct?

It should be inside of your `body` markup if this is proper JSX or HTML structure.

Comment: @DOZBORNE it's neither inside head nor body. I didn't put it in body bc it gives me margins on left and right of the picture that I don't know how to get rid of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization)

> When using layout='fill', the parent element must have position:
> relative
>
> This is necessary for the proper rendering of the image element in
> that layout mode.

What can you do is :

CSS :

add `relative` to the **landingImage** class and remove margin `auto`

```
.landingImage {
  z-index: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
}
```

Wrap Image on the div

```
<div className='landingImage '>
    <Image 
        layout='fill' // required
        objectFit='cover' // change to suit your needs
        src='orcas' //
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Now the image fills the width like I wanted, but its height also grew proportionally. Is there a way to keep its original height?

Comment: You can change object from `cover` to `fill`. and if that helps don't forget to mark the my as answer

Comment: changing object from cover to fill still made the height grow... do you know any way to make the height its original height and stretch the image instead?:(